# Can I produce a square wave(basically a clock) from a USB port on my Laptop? If yes how?

Tags: clock, laptop

Can I produce a square wave(basically a clock) from a USB port on my Laptop?
  If yes how ?
Briefly explaining, I am using ad9834 in a project and this chip needs a clock  of any frequency ranging from 1MHz to 75MHz. This project is powered by USB ports of a Laptop. So i want to generate a clock. 
Also I am using ATXmega 128A3u(on a board, which has 16MHz crystal oscillator) to control the above said chip. So, is there any code to  access this clock?

Comment: what frequency do you need?

Comment: my old lenovo t400 laptop had a DC-coupled headphone socket, you could get a square wave of up-to about 1.5V amplitude from that if you had the right WAV file to play..

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: This is unanswerable unless we know the frequency you need, and why it needs to be controlled over USB?  Just so you can turn it on or off, or to be able to change the frequency on the fly?

Comment: This is a completely different question...

Answer (score 12):

you can't get a clock out of a bare USB port, but there's devices you can attach that can produce a clock.

eg:

connect a USB serial port  (or usb uart cable like "FTDI" if you want didgital signal level) and send it lots of ASCII "U" characters, you'll get a square wave at frequency 1/2 the baud rate so long as you keep on sending the "UUUUUUU"

Comment: This is great and is about as fast as you can go, but there's a catch: that's not real time at all, the "clock" could stop at any moment and restart a bit later. You are anyway limited by the program/keyboard sending the letter. The sound card is the more real time thing you get in windows.

Comment: "Can't" is a strong word.  Are you sure that some USB devices don't allow for some hack/kludge driver software which makes a square wave?

Comment: We are talking about a bare USB port, i.e. a USB standard compliant hub. It won’t even try enumeration because there are no resistors on the data lines. Even if you add the resistor, USB is symmetrical and asynchronous and the protocol (e.g. the packets have a CRC checksum in the end) won’t allow for a continuous square wave on the data lines.

Comment: @VladimirCravero  typical USB UARTS have a buffer of 100 or more characters (so 1000 baud clock cycles, 500 output pulses) it's not hard to keep that  buffer full using software

Comment: a MSP430 launcpad connects to USB port and can produce a square wave (it's a microcontroller it can do all sorts) Arduino Uno - same deal.

Comment: You don't even need a full Arduino; with a bit of software you can even attach an ATtiny85 to a USB port, viz. Adafruit Trinket or Digistump Digispark.

Comment: An Adafruit Trinket does not expose the USB for serial, just programming.

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't use a serial connection if you have PWM channels available.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't state that you want the frequency controlled via USB just "produced by"

If you are willing to have some IC's then why not use the USB port as a 5V supply and either wire up a 555 or create a simple oscillator out of R-C & a 74HC14 Schmitt inverter

If you want a bit more control, one of the tiny arduino's and a few lines of code to change freq via the USB is doable.

[image]

If however you just want to have a clock appearing at the connector... USB isn't a generic I/O and it has alot of preamble associated with USB